# iPhone - ECGraph plots my graph as a single line on Y axis

Tags: ios4, graph

I am using Xcode 3.2.3 with iOS 4 SDK.

I am preparing a small app for plotting values on a graph. To this end I have used the ECGraph library. I downloaded the sample app and tuned it a bit to suit my purposes. I want the graph to plot time on the X-axis in hours and a simple int value on the Y-axis.

My problem: When I do select the option of creating a point in ECGraph as (date, value), I can see the graph if the scale on the X-axis i.e. time unit is date. If i change the time unit to HOUR, the graph is a single line on the Y-axis where the Y-axis plots are correct, but the X-axis points are always the origin.

[image: graph shown is not as expected, pt 2 is (9, 13)]

I have added the code from my UIView file here. Its simply the one taken from the demo app, given with the ECGraph lib download and then tuned for my stuff.

DisplayView.m:

```
    //
    //  DisplayView.m
    //  ECGraphic
    //
    //  Created by ris on 10-4-17.
    //  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "DisplayView.h"
    #import "ECCommon.h"
    #import "ECGraphPoint.h"
    #import "ECGraphLine.h"
    #import "ECGraphItem.h"

    @implementation DisplayView


    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
        if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
            // Initialization code
        }
        return self;
    }


    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

        // Drawing code
        CGContextRef _context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        ECGraph *graph = [[ECGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 350) withContext:_context isPortrait:YES];

        ECGraphPoint *point7 = [[ECGraphPoint alloc] init];
        point7.yValue = 7;
        point7.xDateValue = [ECCommon dOfS:@"08" withFormat:kDEFAULT_HOUR_FORMAT];

        ECGraphPoint *point8 = [[ECGraphPoint alloc] init];
        point8.yValue = 13;
        point8.xDateValue = [ECCommon dOfS:@"09" withFormat:kDEFAULT_HOUR_FORMAT];

        ECGraphPoint *point9 = [[ECGraphPoint alloc] init];
        point9.yValue = 1;
        point9.xDateValue = [ECCommon dOfS:@"10" withFormat:kDEFAULT_HOUR_FORMAT];

        ECGraphPoint *point10 = [[ECGraphPoint alloc] init];
        point10.yValue = 3;
        point10.xDateValue = [ECCommon dOfS:@"11" withFormat:kDEFAULT_HOUR_FORMAT];


        //NSArray *pts3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:point7,point8,point9, point10, nil];
        NSArray *pts3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:point7,point8, nil];
        ECGraphLine *line3 = [[ECGraphLine alloc] init];
        line3.isXDate = YES;
        line3.points = pts3;



        NSArray *lines = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:line3,nil];
        [graph setXaxisTitle:@"Hours"];
        [graph setYaxisTitle:@"Energy consumed in Watts"];
        [graph setGraphicTitle:@"Weekly consumption of your device"];
        [graph setXaxisDateFormat:kDEFAULT_HOUR_FORMAT];
        [graph setDelegate:self];
        [graph setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:220/255.0 green:220/255.0 blue:220/255.0 alpha:1]];
        [graph setPointType:ECGraphPointTypeCircle];
        [graph drawCurveWithLines:lines lineWidth:2 color:[UIColor blackColor]];


    }


    - (void)dealloc {
        [super dealloc];
    }


    @end
```

Comment: did u find any solution?